# What are the possible part of speech combinations for compound nouns?

Tags: parts-of-speech, compounds, attributive-nouns

I am currently working through allowable part of speech combinations for the first two words of an English sentence.  It seems troubling to me to allow the first two words of a sentence to both be nouns, but that may well be valid.  One such circumstance is with compound nouns where it is rendered as two separate words (I am neglecting hyphenated and one-word versions here).

If I were to have the following sentence:

> Tea time is at 3:00 every afternoon.

I would naturally think of *time* as a noun of course, but I might describe *tea* as an adjective in this case.

So which combinations of parts of speech can a compound noun take and how would one distinguish which is the correct labeling for the compound noun?

Comment: I'm afraid that no information can be gained from a listing of the allowable POS combinations for "the first two words of an English sentence." The first two words can be just about anything, given the way English syntax changes word order. If you were looking at [Constituents](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAConstituent.htm) instead of just two words, you might get somewhere. But the first two words have nothing useful to offer. Sorry.

Comment: I am more tolerant of the analysis and classification of individual words in structures than John Lawler is, but admit that it does get very messy when say the compound noun _particle board_ is classified quite differently from its hyphenated and closed variants _particle-board_ and _particleboard_ (all in use). _Teatime_ is usually solid, but I'd class _tea bag_ as a compound noun also. Both are formed from a noun + noun combination of free morphemes. I wouldn't class _store manager_ as a compound noun, but would class _store_ here as as a 'noun modifier'.

Comment: Check the structure and range of English compounds at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound and _noun modifiers_ at http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/noun-modifiers etc. Also, on _lexical items_ rather than words as being the true 'building blocks of English' at http://www.wordnik.com/words/lexical%20item

Comment: Not compound nouns, but lists can start sentences with 2 or more nouns - "Ham, cheese and tomato are good ingredients for a sandwich."

Comment: @Mynamite I do agree with you on that one, thanks.  I didn't say this outright, but I am a computational linguist and so when using taggers, the comma would count as a token and therefore possess a part of speech tag meaning it would not be two nouns for me.  Just a different perspective of looking at things I guess.

Comment: @demongolem I thought it might be something like that. Does 'and' also count as a token, as in "Ham and cheese go together well"?

Comment: @Mynamite Likely a tagger would say _Ham_ is NN (noun singular) and _and_ is CC (coordinating conjunction) meaning that they are both tokens and once again we do not have 2 nouns in a row.  However, it all depends on how the tagger is trained.  In this case, I don't think _ham and cheese_ would be learned as a compound noun due to its rareness in written text even though I am sure it is very tasty.

Comment: @demongolem I would not consider sensible any analysis that did not treat the 'Bacon and eggs' in _Bacon and eggs are expensive in Elbonia_ (or _Eggs and bacon are expensive in Elbonia_) as three tokens, but in _Bacon and eggs is my favourite breakfast_ as unitary.

Answer (score 1):

English can use *attributive noun phrases* in place of many expressions with "of." For example, "her box of poems" can become "her poem box". Linguists don't like to model this by saying that poem has become an adjective because of the way they interact with real adjectives. E.g. "Her Elizabethan poetry box." Even without the hyphen, most readers just can't accept that Elizabethan modifies box. So "Poem boxes lined her shelves" would indeed begin with two nouns, if you follow that model.

Comment: That’s exactly right. This is a [noun–noun combination](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/noun-adjuncts/info). Just becomes adjectives modify nouns does **not** mean that all words that modify nouns are necessarily adjectives. They aren’t.